# Is the following function Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Given is the function $$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}, & x\in \mathbb{I}\cap [0,1]\\
x^3, &x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\end{array}\right.$$

I have to see if $f$ is L-integrable on $[0,1]$. By definition $f$ has to be a measurable bounded function defined on a set $E$ of finite measure to be L-integrable on $E$. I have problems with the boundary part, because if $x=\varepsilon >0$ is a really small irrational number, wouldn't $f(x)\rightarrow \infty$, and thus wouldn't that imply that $f$ isn't bounded.

Comment: A Lebesgue-integrable function need not be bounded.

Comment: I know that, but we've been prooving L-integrability only by definition so that is the only way I'm familiar at this point with.

Comment: "I'm familiar with" is not part of the definition. What is the definition you're using?

Comment: If $f$ is a bounded measurable function defined on a finite measurable set $E$, then $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $E$ and $\int_E f(x)\; dm=\inf \int_E \psi(x)$, $\forall \psi \geq f$.

Comment: @zermelovac Then you must specify who $\psi$ is and what does the symbol $\int_{E}\psi(x)$ means.

Comment: That part I ususally don't use, the TA has given us that definition, to prove that there exists a L-integral, but for calculating it we've been using theorems like if $f=g$ almost everywhere on $E$, then $\int_E f\; dm=\int_E g\; dm$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write out an answer in terms of Baby Rudin ch. 11, but be warned there are other ways to construct the Lebesgue integral.  Your definition of Lebesgue integrable, which requires that $f$ be bounded, is anomalous.  $f$ is obviously not bounded, as you point out.

$\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ has measure zero because it is countable (Rudin 11.11(f)), and so do any of its subsets for the same reason.  The function $f$ is equal to $1/\sqrt{x}$ except on this set of measure zero (assuming $\mathbb{I}=\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$).  For any real $a$, the set $\{x:f(x)>a\}$ equals the set of $x$ for which $1/\sqrt{x}>a$, perhaps plus or minus a countable set of measure zero.  The set of $x$ for which $1/\sqrt{x}>a$ is measurable, indeed open.  The union and difference of measurable sets are measurable because the measurable sets form a $\sigma$-ring aka $\sigma$-algebra (Rudin 11.10). Thus, $\{x:f(x)>a\}$ is measurable for all $a$, and $f$ is measurable (Rudin 11.13).

The conventional definition of "Lebesgue integrable" for a nonnegative function like $f$ requires only that it be measurable and that its integral be finite (Rudin 11.21-11.22).  As for the finiteness of the integral, $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ equals $\int_0^1 dx/\sqrt{x}$ because we can ignore the set of measure zero $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ (Rudin 11.25).  The latter integral is readily calculated because $d\sqrt{x}/dx=1/(2\sqrt{x})$, and is finite.

Comment: Why can you say that $\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^11/\sqrt{x}\mathrm{d}x$ ? If $1/\sqrt{x}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}a_k\mathbb{1}_{A_k}$ with $a_k$ non-negative real numbers and $A_k$ measurable sets of $[0,1]$, then $\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x:=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}a_k\lambda\left(A_k\right)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, but $\int_0^11/\sqrt{x}\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{I}(x)\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}a_k \lambda\left(A_k\cap\mathbb{I}\right)$ ; so there is equality beteween the both integrals iff $\lambda\left(A_k\right)=\lambda\left(A_k\cap\mathbb{I}\right)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The reason I say that the two integrals are equal is the result in Rudin 11.25 that functions which differ on a set of measure zero have the same integral if it exists.  In addition, for any measurable set $A_k\subset [0,1]$, we have $\lambda(A_k)=\lambda(A_k\cap \mathbb{I})$ ($\lambda$ denoting Lebesgue measure) because, given that $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{I}\cup\mathbb{Q}$, by additivity $\lambda(A_k)=\lambda(A_k\cap \mathbb{I})+\lambda(A_k\cap \mathbb{Q})$ and the latter is zero, $\mathbb{Q}$ being countable.

Comment: Ok, it was in your quotations of Rudin, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

$f=f_1 1_{\mathbb{I}\cap [0,1]}+f_2 1_{\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]}$, where $f_1(x)=x^{-1/2}$ and $f_2(x)=x^3$. Conclude integrating both sides.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that notation $1_{\mathbb{I}\cap [0,1]}$ and $1_{\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]}$, what does it mean?

Comment: If $A$ is a set, $1_A$ is the function $1_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $1_A(x)=0$ if $x\notin A$. $1_A$ is called indicator function of $A$

Comment: Ohh, I get it know. We've only been using the notation $\chi_A(x)$, for the indicator function.

Answer (score 0):

One can write
$$f=x\mapsto x^3\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{I}\cap[0,1]}(x)$$
where I guess that $\mathbb{I}$ is the set of irrational numbers. Now $[0,1]$, $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{I}$ are measurable sets, with $\mathbb{Q}$ being negligible. You can conclude that $f$ is measurable.

As for the integral, if $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue's measure, then you have
\begin{align}\int_{[0,1]} f\mathrm{d}\lambda & = \int_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}} f\mathrm{d}\lambda+\int_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb{I}} f\mathrm{d}\lambda \\
& = \int_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb{I}} f\mathrm{d}\lambda \\
& = \int_{[0,1]} f\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{I}}\mathrm{d}\lambda \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}.
\end{align}

Comment: What confirms the existence of the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: @zermelovac The existence of the Lebesgue integral of $f$ comes from the fat that $x\mapsto x^3\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(x)$ and $x\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{I}\cap[0,1]}(x)$ are Lebesgue integrable maps.

Comment: What do you mean by a map?

Comment: @zermelovac A function if you prefer. Seeing your other comments, I am asking myself if the answers provided until now are really helpfull ; can you use the fact that continuous functions on compact sets are Lebesgue integrable ?

Comment: I know that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is bounded and Lebesgue measurable, but I can't see that on my sets, because every point is a point of discontinuity. If I would understand that part, everything else would be simple do prove.

Comment: @zermelovac Ok, so the continuity was for $x^3$ and $1/\sqrt{x}$, at least on $[1/n,1]$ because of the singularity at $0$ of the inverse function. So, by definition of the characteristic functions, the integral on $[0,1]$ of $x^3\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is the integral on $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ of $x^3$, which exists because $\int_{[0,1]}x^3\mathrm{d}x$ exists and $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\subset[0,1]$. Idem for the integral of $1/\sqrt{x}\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{I}(x)$, except that you only know that the integral $\int_{[1/n,1]}1/\sqrt{x}\mathrm{d}x$ exists. You need there a convergence theorem.

Comment: Do you mean the  Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @zermelovac Yes, or here the Beppo-Levi theorem or monotone convergence theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem). You need to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[1/n,1]\cap\mathbb{I}}1/\sqrt{x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{[0,1] \cap\mathbb{I}}1/\sqrt{x} \mathrm{d}x$ ; use Beppo-Levi with the functions $f_n(x)=1/\sqrt{x}\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{I}\cap[1/n,1]}(x)>0$ for $n\geq1$.